# Help with an expression that uses お笑い vocabulary

Tags: grammar, words

> 突っ込みどころ満載
>
> I just have to butt in here. / I'd love to put my two cents in.

I am having a hard time figuring out this expression. I see it uses vocabulary particular to お笑い, but I would appreciate if someone would specify which meaning each word takes on in this instance, and how they work together. I am sure a better translation could be made as well. Sorry for so many questions in one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most typical Japanese comedy style (漫才) consists of

1. Someone saying/doing a silly thing (ぼけ) and
2. Someone pointing that out (つっこみ).

(Confer my answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3316).)

ぼけ is the joking part as seen in jokes in many countries, but one difference form the commedy style often seen these days in Western countries is that the ぼけ person himself/herself does not make it explicit that it is a joke. Rather, they pretend that they are not aware of the funniness of what they are saying or doing (In Western commedy, a counterpart will be something like Mr. Beans). The ぼけ person makes jokes at certain points in the talk, where the つっこみ person is expected/supposed to pause the talk and point out or explain to the audience what the joke was. These points are `突っ込みどころ` "points where the 突っ込み is supposed to be done". `満載` means "loaded full of". It is used here metaphorically. Following Yadokari's suggestion, the English counterpart of the person with the つっこみ-role will be "the straight man".

Syntactically, `満載` is the predicate predicated of its argument `突っ込みどころ`, which is a compound noun consisting of `突っ込み` （verb stem used as a nominal） and `ところ` "place" (which underwent sequential voicing (連濁) to become `どころ`).

Recently, this expression has evolved into meaning, outside of the commedy context, that someone's talk or act is so silly or stupid that there are full of points where one can point that out.

Comment: Thank you. Is the 突っ込み in 突っ込みどころ the person (つっこみ) or the action?

Comment: @yadokari The action.

Comment: Would this expression be used by itself in a manner similar to my revised translations?
...I saw this expression when a japanese person was talking about their top ten english grammar peeves.

Comment: Also in case you're interested I think a decent equivalent term to つっこみ would be "the straight man". There was an older tradition of western comedy as well, kind of like laurel and hardy, where this applies in a similar fashion- a dumb guy unwittingly makes a joke and the straight man corrects/chastises him.

Comment: @yadokari Yes. I think the nuance that you now have is in good like with the meaning of the Japanese expression.

Comment: @yadokari I see. I didn't know that. I will correct my answer. "the straight man" seems to fit.